# Nginx dynamic location with map

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have multiple services that run under the `/service/<service_name>` block, each one for each service. This works just fine but it's really long and bloated since every block has blocks on it's on. An example:

```
location /service/firstservice {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8501/;
        .
        .
        .


        location /service/firstservice/static {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501/static/;
        }
        location /service/firstservice/healthz {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501/healthz;
        }

        location /service/firstservice/vendor {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501/vendor;
        }

        location /service/firstservice/stream {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501/stream;
                .
                .
                .
        }
}
```

And that's only for one service. I was thinking about making only one block with the base subdirectory and a map that points to the respective port:

```
map $uri $serviceport {
    default             invalid;
    ~^/service/firstservice/.*        8501;
    ~^/service/secondservice/.*       8502;
    ~^/service/thirdservice/.*        8503; 
}

server {

        ...

        location /service/(?<servicename>.+)$/ {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:$serviceport;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

                location /service/$servicename/static {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:$serviceport/static/;
                }

                ...
        }
}
```

However nginx test always fails indicating that either the regex is bad or the logic is either not supported or just bad implementation.

Any guide or help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I don't understand why are you using those nested locations at your first example, it should be enough just to use

```
location /service/firstservice/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8501/;
    ...
}
```

Next, you can't use a variable to specify a location (just answered the related question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1091091/the-location-directive-has-no-effect-when-it-contains-a-variable#:%7E:text=https%3A//serverfault.com/a/1091095/498657)). If you want to change an URI passed to the backend, you should use a `rewrite` directive to do it (just answered the related question [here](https://serverfault.com/a/1091026/498657)):

```
map $servicename $serviceport {
    firstservice        8501;
    secondservice       8502;
    thirdservice        8503; 
}
server {
    ...
    location ~ ^/service/(?<servicename>firstservice|secondservice|thirdservice)/ {
        rewrite ^/service/[^/]+(/.*) $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$serviceport;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```